# SQL simple update query not working - Beginner

Tags: sql, ms-access

My understanding is that a query update is like find and replace. I want to find records in my Result Table using criteria from my form and update those records with information entered into my form. I think you will understand my intent from the SQL I've written here.  However, I'm getting a syntax error so can someone please explain why this does not work in Access 2010.

```
UPDATE  TBLResult
SET [RepsOrTime] = [Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![RepsOrTime]
WHERE ([Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![StudentID]) AND ([Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![TestID])
```

Comment: The syntax error may be caused by the `;` at the end of the first line of your query, or the `}` in the second line...

Comment: In the where condition is the condition missing `([Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![StudentID])  = <value> and ([Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![TestID]) = <value1>`

Comment: Thanks folks - both of these answers have improved my understanding of Query Update.  The first error is frustrating as my actual SQL statement didn't have the curly bracket - dratted sausage fingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your criteria are missing:

```
UPDATE TBLResult
SET [RepsOrTime] = [Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![RepsOrTime]
WHERE StudentID = [Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![StudentID] 
   AND TestID = [Forms]![FRMRecordResults]![TestID]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the correct syntax and pointing out the importance of the criteria bit. My new query works a treat!